# Pandas DataFrame value_counts dict of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to create a dictionary where the keys are pandas columns (all type object), and the keys are dictionaries with the `value_counts()` for each respective column.

I tried to do it this way, but I'm getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`:

`value_counts_dict = {(c, dict(df[c].value_counts())) for c in df}`

This alternative works, but it gives me a list of tuples instead:

`value_counts_tuples = [(c, dict(df[c].value_counts())) for c in df]`

If this is possible would someone please show me how?

Comment: I think you meant `dict((c, dict(df[c].value_counts())) for c in df)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
value_counts_dict = {c: df[c].value_counts().to_dict() for c in df}
```

Or:

```
value_counts_dict = {c: dict(df[c].value_counts()) for c in df}
```